# Three.js - Shadow.bias fixes shadow static, but moves the shadows. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a scene with a light casting shadows. It does well, except from the `static` from the shadow. Like so:

[image]

When I add a simple `light.shadow.bias = -0.005;`:

[image]

It fixes the issue, but causes another. As you can see from the building's shadow, the shadows are completely out of place! Is there a way to fix this, or an alternative method of getting rid of the `shadow static`?

Comment: What do you mean with "except from the static from the shadow"?

Comment: @Mugen87 from the first picture, if you can see there is `shadow noise` or static, on the character's head. When I try to use the `shadow.bias` method, it smooths the shadow out, but causes the shadow to change position, giving it a weird cut look, as you can see from the building's shadow in the 2nd picture

Comment: Can you try to mitigate the issue with the [normalBias](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=lightsh#api/en/lights/shadows/LightShadow.normalBias) property instead?

Comment: @Mugen87 that did the trick :) Thank you

Comment: @Mugen87 can you put this as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: Okay, I've added an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to mitigate the issue by using the new [normalBias](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/lights/shadows/LightShadow.normalBias) property. From the documentation:

> Defines how much the position used to query the shadow map is offset along the object normal. The default is 0. Increasing this value can be used to reduce shadow acne especially in large scenes where light shines onto geometry at a shallow angle. The cost is that shadows may appear distorted.

Comment: Thanks again! :)

Comment: Ah thanks dude, was struggling there as well. Simulating a sunlight over a city leads to a huge camera area and artifacts, that need to be fixed with a bias but bias on -0.00035 creates this gap as well, normalBias doesn't but I have to set it on 0.45.